# Too late in applying for childcare allowance in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, children

Our son started daycare in February. We had been wrongly assuming that we could apply for childcare allowance (kinderopvangtoeslag) at the end of the year, with the tax returns. When we found out this was not the case, we ended up applying for it in August. However, it seems you can only apply for the allowance for the last 3 months. So, we lost 3 months of allowance. Considering the cost of our daycare, this is a significant amount.

Is there a way for recovering the 3 months of lost allowance or at least a part of it?

Answer (score 1):

From the Belastingdienst [Ik wil een toeslag aanvragen voor 2017](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/toeslagen/aanvragen/toeslag_2017_aanvragen/) page:

> Tot wanneer kan ik kinderopvangtoeslag aanvragen?
>   U moet kinderopvangtoeslag aanvragen binnen 3 maanden na de maand waarin u recht op de toeslag hebt. Vraagt u de toeslag later aan? Dan loopt u een deel van de toeslag mis.
>   Voorbeeld
>   Uw kind gaat vanaf 10 april 2017 naar de kinderopvang. U moet dan uiterlijk 31 juli 2017 kinderopvangtoeslag aanvragen. Vraagt u de toeslag pas in september 2017 aan? Dan krijgt u toeslag vanaf 1 juni 2017. De toeslag voor april en mei loopt u dus mis.

Translation:

> Until when can I apply for childcare allowance?
>   You must apply for childcare allowance within 3 months of the month in which you are entitled to the surcharge. Do you request the surcharge later? Then you will lose part of the fee.
>   Example
>   Your child goes to childcare from April 10, 2017. You must apply for childcare allowance by 31 July 2017. Do you request the surcharge in September 2017? Then you will receive an allowance from June 1, 2017. The fee for April and May will be missed.

This rule [started on 1-1-2014](https://www.kindercreche.nl/nieuws/toeslag-2014-binnen-drie-maanden-aanvragen).

**There is no way around this**. This is e.g. confirmed by many people on this (Dutch) page [Bezwaar aantekenen tegen te laat aanvragen kinderopvangtoeslag 2015 zinvol?](https://kassa.bnnvara.nl/vraag-beantwoord/vraag/geldzaken-recht/bezwaar-aantekenen-tegen-te-laat-aanvragen-kinderopvangtoeslag-2015-zinvol)